# Multithreading torchscript

Tags: c++, multithreading, jit, torchscript

I would like to use the same model in multi-threading, but when I define the model on each thread separately, the program allocates the same amount of memory in the GPU regardless of the number of threads, and when I try to increase the number of threads the performance drops. It seems that each thread is using the same model, even if they are allocated on different stack. How can I separate them ?

```cpp
 int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    std::thread first(thread1);
    first.detach();
    std::thread first2(thread2, "window3");
    first2.detach();
    std::thread first3(thread2, "window4");
    first3.detach();
    std::thread first4(thread2, "window5");
    first4.detach();
    std::thread first5(thread2, "window6");
    first5.detach();

    
    while(true){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    

    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
void thread1()
{
    bool is_gpu = true;
    torch::DeviceType device_type;
    if (torch::cuda::is_available() && is_gpu) {
        device_type = torch::kCUDA;
    } else {
        device_type = torch::kCPU;
    }

    // load network
    std::string weights = "/home/pawel/Documents/libtorch-yolov5/weights/yolov5s.torchscript";
    Detector* detector = new Detector(weights, device_type);

    // load input image to warm up
    std::string source = "/home/pawel/Documents/libtorch-yolov5/images/bus.jpg";
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(source);

    // run once to warm up
    std::cout << "Run once on empty image" << std::endl;
    auto temp_img = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, CV_32FC3);
    detector->Run(temp_img, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    // set up threshold
    float conf_thres = 0.4;
    float iou_thres = 0.5;

    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    // load class names from dataset for visualization
    std::vector<std::string> class_names = LoadNames("../weights/coco.names");

    cap.open(0);
    while (true){
        
        cap.read(img);
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto result = detector->Run(img, conf_thres, iou_thres);
        auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start);
        //std::cout<< "[1] " << duration.count() << "ms \n"; 
        Demo(img, result, class_names, "window1");
    }
    
}
```

```cpp
void thread2(std::string name = "window2")
{

    bool is_gpu = true;
    torch::DeviceType device_type;
    if (torch::cuda::is_available() && is_gpu) {
        device_type = torch::kCUDA;
    } else {
        device_type = torch::kCPU;
    }

    

    // load network
    std::string weights = "/home/pawel/Documents/libtorch-yolov5/weights/yolov5s.torchscript";
    Detector* detector = new Detector(weights, device_type);

    // load input image
    std::string source = "/home/pawel/Documents/libtorch-yolov5/images/bus.jpg";
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(source);

    // run once to warm up
    std::cout << "Run once on empty image" << std::endl;
    auto temp_img = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows, img.cols, CV_32FC3);
    detector->Run(temp_img, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    // set up threshold
    float conf_thres = 0.4;
    float iou_thres = 0.5;

    // load class names from dataset for visualization
    std::vector<std::string> class_names = LoadNames("../weights/coco.names");

    cv::VideoCapture cap;

    cap.open("/home/pawel/Documents/libtorch-yolov5/images/film.mkv");
    while (true){
        //cap.read(img);
        auto result = detector->Run(img, conf_thres, iou_thres);
        Demo(img, result, class_names, name);
    }

}
```

```cpp
Detector::Detector(const std::string& model_path, const torch::DeviceType& device_type) : device_(device_type) {
    try {
        // Deserialize the ScriptModule from a file using torch::jit::load().
        module_ = torch::jit::load(model_path);
        std::cout << "to ja 1 \n";
    }
    catch (const c10::Error& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error loading the model!\n";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    half_ = (device_ != torch::kCPU);
    module_.to(device_);

    if (half_) {
        module_.to(torch::kHalf);
    }

    module_.eval();
}
```

When i run 1 thread:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YPlW.png)

```cpp
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // inference
    torch::jit::IValue output = module_.forward(inputs);


    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);
    std::cout << "inference takes : " << duration.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZNcJ.png)

When i run 6 threads:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgXNi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltdFx.png)

The above code was created based on https://github.com/yasenh/libtorch-yolov5

Comment: Please post a small sample of your code so that it will be helpful for other users to see what you are trying to do and where you are facing issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I edited the main post